# How to apply searching on aggregate function with normal column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have a two table one is survey_list and another is survey_summary in which in which i have to make a query which can sort all the column from both the tables
but in which i am using one count function also so that i was unable to find out how can i sort the value which is coming from count function with the normal column.

Below is my table structure.

first table is survey_list

```
..........................
id   surveyname   status
..........................
1      test1      Active
2      test2      Inactive
```

second table survey_summary

```
................................
id    userid       survey_id
................................
1      46              1
2      47              2
3      48              1
4      49              2
```

in the survey_summary table survey_id is the fk of survey_list
which has a id.I have tried below query to search all the column
but i was unable to apply searching on count column.

```
SELECT survey_list.`id`,
       survey_list.`survey_name`,
       survey_list.`status`,
       count(survey_list.`id`)AS COUNT
FROM `survey_list`
LEFT JOIN survey_summary ON survey_list.`id`=survey_summary.`survey_id`
WHERE survey_list.`survey_name` LIKE '2%'
  OR survey_list.`status` LIKE '2%'
GROUP BY survey_list.`id`
```

Please help me to apply searching on the count column as well.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: how exactly do you need to search on the count column? something like counted items > 5?

Answer (score 0):

Is it that you are looking for?

```
   SELECT survey_list.`id`,
           survey_list.`survey_name`,
           survey_list.`status`,
           count(survey_list.`id`)AS cnt
    FROM `survey_list`
    LEFT JOIN survey_summary ON survey_list.`id`=survey_summary.`survey_id`
    WHERE survey_list.`survey_name` LIKE '2%'
      OR survey_list.`status` LIKE '2%'
    GROUP BY survey_list.`id`
    HAVING
     cnt > 0
```

Comment: no actually let's undertand the scenrio once again suppose i have table in which i am showing this columns id,survey_name,status,count.know second thing is suppose i have a search box in which user can enter the value of any column so according to this i have to apply searching on all the tables.

Comment: for this if user can enter any value of survey_name  on search field then i have applied the like statement for this and for  the same status column as well but suppose if users can enters the value of count field e.g.2 then how i can apply like statement on this aggregate function.

Comment: HAVING
     cnt > 2

though consider using number comparison (as count is definitely a number)